# Xcode server bot error "Trigger exited with non zero status 2"

Tags: xcode, bots, carthage, siren

Hey I wanna set up a Xcode server, in order to work properly I need to get the extension "Siren" to get installed before the bot runs and tests the Xcode project.

The problems here is that every time I integrate the bot to test my app it resets my installed Carthage extensions...

I think I need a pre integration script who installs the missing extensions into the bot when it starts.

At the moment I wrote as pre integration script (called "Install dependencies"):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Users/catrobat/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/9194b282ad9904370a8be66eb400f02d/Source/Catty
make init
```

The folder dictionary is where my bot gets created and make init is the command in order to get home-brew to install "Siren" and more in the make file.

But it doesn't work and I get the error "*Trigger exited with non-zero status 2*"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please add [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Xcode Server* exposes `XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR` which is just what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
pushd "${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}"
make init
```